Troubleshooting KivyMD Import Issues in Python
I tried to check where KivyMD exists. I have already activated the ptvenv, which represents the virtual environment I am working with for this project, and installed KivyMD. Here is the output of pip freeze:
asyncgui==0.6.3
asynckivy==0.6.4
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
docutils==0.21.2
idna==3.10
Kivy==2.3.0
kivy-deps.angle==0.4.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.3.1
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.7.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
kivy-garden.mapview==1.0.6
kivymd==1.1.1
materialyoucolor==2.0.9
pillow==10.4.0
Pygments==2.18.0
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==306
requests==2.32.3
urllib3==2.2.3

import os
import kivymd

print(os.path.dirname(kivymd.__file__))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\public_transportation_v2\tester.py", line 2, in <module>
    import kivymd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'

